# Function that removes the first letter of a word and attaches it at the end (Haskell)

Tags: haskell

I am stuck with the following question:
**Write a function `mangle :: String -> String` which removes the first letter of a word and attaches it at the end.**

What I have so far:

```
mangle :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]       (I suspect that this is possibly wrong)
mangle x
  = a ++ b
  where
    a = tail x
    b = head x
```

Can anyone help me and tell/explain what I should put on the top?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems here. First of all, the signature of `mangle` should be `mangle :: [a] -> [a]`. Indeed, it takes as parameter a `[a]`, a list of `a`s, and it returns a list of `a`s.

Another problem is that `head :: [a] -> a` returns a single element. So you can not use `(++) :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]` since that expects two lists with the same type of items.

You thus need to wrap the `head x` in a singleton list:

```
mangle :: [a] -> [a]
mangle x = tail x ++ [head x]
```

There is still another problem: `head` and `tail` can not work with empty lists. You thus probably should write a base-case for an empty list as well.

We can make the function more elegant by performing pattern matching instead of using `head` and `tail`, like:

```
mangle :: [a] -> [a]
mangle [] = …
mangle (x:xs) = xs ++ [x]
```